# Highlist highest value arc in donut chart in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation, flutter-plugin, flutter-packages

I am trying to display donut chart with the highest value highlighted with border or some style.

By default flutter doesn't let me add styles to donut chart. I also tried circular chart but still no success.

Answer (score 1):

I made something similar using CustomPainter.

Look here for some ideas https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/CustomPainter-class.html